# Understanding the end of YellowBrickRoad

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, yellowbrickroad

The critics gave [YellowBrickRoad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YellowBrickRoad) some pretty bad ratings, but I have to say I enjoyed it quite a bit. However, the end bothers me to no end -- I just don't understand it.

Is it that the main character was stuck in the 1940's? Or is everything just happening in his mind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its left deliberately vague but I did not get the sense that it was either all in his head or that he was stuck in the 1940s, but rather that it was a supernatural phenomenon where each person's fate depended on their personality and character.

The closest to a definitive answer that I could find is from an [interview with the film-makers](http://www.dreadcentral.com/news/44775/exclusive-andy-mitton-and-jesse-holland-talk-yellowbrickroad):

> We purposely left the ending open for interpretation because this
>   movie is about the journey- where our characters end up at the end of
>   YellowBrickRoad is dependent on their fears and motivations. Every
>   character ends up with a different fate because of who they are.